# Two identical codes to format date one doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have two columns in database `Time_1` and `Time_2` which store timestamps.

**Then on the view I have this:**

```
<div class="time">Time_1</div>
<pre>{{ $order->order_date->format('Y/m/d g:i a')}} | {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($order->order_date))->diffForHumans() }}</pre>
<div class="time">Time_2</div>
<pre>{{ $order->payment_status_date->format('Y/m/d g:i a') }} | {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($order->payment_status_date))->diffForHumans() }}</pre>
```

**Expected result:**

```
Time_1 = 2017/03/14 10:59 am | 1 hour ago
Time_2 = 2017/03/14 10:59 am | 1 hour ago
```

But I got page break on second time like it's stopped loading of page there.

**The error is doesn't make sense to me:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\PlainDisplayer::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given,

```
var_dump($order->order_date) -> `object(Carbon\Carbon)#457 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-03-14 10:59:37.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }`

var_dump($order->payment_status_date) -> `string(19) "2016-12-31 07:11:05"`
```

The question is why since both are stored as timestamps and I'm using same carbon .. etc I've got this difference and how to fix this?

Comment: Are they both defined in the `$dates` array of your model?

Comment: Whats not so funny is that the given `error` comes from a process that wants to show the real error (`Exception\PlainDisplayer`). But seems that there is a bug/issue within laravel that the `Exception` is thrown as `Error` instance. So the real error can not show up.

Comment: Check your laravel logs to see what happens.

Comment: How to see if both are in `$dates` array.. And how come one is in but second isn't in the array since they come from same source e.g. database

Comment: @Onix, the error is in the question ( from laravel.log file ). I don't know why I get the error that says that can't show me the error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the second date added to to $dates array in your model, so Laravel knows to treat it like a Carbon instance.

```
protected $dates = ['Time_1', 'Time_2'];
```

Comment: Okay, this fixed the issue. I don't understand why Laravel need to specify them in the Model..As I understand this the Carbon should take whole data which is in array and array should be whole row for the given ID, no?

Comment: Because Laravel automatically converts these database columns to Carbon Instances which allows you to use those format methods. By default it only knows about the created_at and updated_at fields. So if you have more, you have to tell it to view them as dates.

Comment: Thanks. That's strange to me why is working like this.. and why didn't take all dates column which I give to Laravel without explicitly to tell which are they in the Model like this